I am unable to login into the admin dashboard side there is error 403 (unauthorized access) coming on console
i am trying to make the login page which will be same for user and admin . i differentiated between them by putting a checkbox in form and the login for userDashboard is working properly but the AdminDashboard is not working properly it is giving me  Error like below, Here i'm logging into the system as a admin but the Previliges given to the admin are not accessible for him . He can not see any record or do any CRUD operation on it
127.0.0.1:5000/api/users:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (FORBIDDEN)
AdminDashboard.js:25 Error fetching users:
AxiosError
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
"Request failed with status code 403"
name
: "AxiosError"
 const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/${isAdmin ? "admin/login" : "login"}`,
        { email, password },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data.role);
        setIsAuthenticated(true); // Update parent state
        setUserRole(response.data.role); // Set user role
    

        // Role-based redirection
        const roleRedirect = {
          admin: "/admin-dashboard",
          employee: "/user-dashboard"
        };

        navigate(roleRedirect[response.data.role] || "/login");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        setError("Invalid email or password");
      } else {
        setError("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
      }
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchUsers = async () => {
     try {
       const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users", { withCredentials: true });
       console.log("Fetch Users Response:", response); // Debug response
       if (response.status === 200) {
         setUsers(response.data);
       }
     } catch (error) {
       console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
       if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
         setError("Unauthorized access: Only admins can view this page.");
         navigate("/login"); // Redirect to login page if unauthorized
       } else {
         setError("Error fetching user data.");
       }
     }
   };

   fetchUsers(); // Trigger fetch when component mounts
 }, [navigate]);

@app.route('/api/admin/login', methods=['POST'])
def admin_login():
    data = request.json
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=data.get('email')).first()
    if user and user.role == 'admin' and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password_hash, data.get('password')):
        session['user_id'] = user.id
        session['role'] = user.role
        session.permanent = True  # Make the session permanent
        print("Session set for admin:", session)  # Debug: Check the session
        return jsonify({"message": "Admin login successful", "role": user.role, "id": user.id}), 200
    return jsonify({"message": "Invalid credentials or not an admin"}), 401

@app.route('/api/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():
    print("Current session in get_users:", session)  # Debug: Check session content
    if 'role' in session and session['role'] == 'admin':
        users = User.query.all()
        users_data = [
            {"id": user.id, "name": user.name, "email": user.email, "role": user.role, "department": user.department}
            for user in users
        ]
        return jsonify(users_data), 200
    return jsonify({"message": "Unauthorized: Only admins can view all users"}), 403

This is frontend and Backend code regarding that 403 Error

It looks like your session content doesn't have the "admin" role, hence why you are getting returned 403.

Session set for admin: <SecureCookieSession {'user_id': 5, 'role': 'admin', '_permanent': True}> here at backend I'm getting like this in which a session cookie is stored with role. Or you are talking about something else?
please let me if you have anymore suggestions thanks for answering
